# Asserting that mixed native and numpy types are equal

Tags: python, numpy, types, assert

I have two variables being passed into a function at which point I would like to assert they are of the same type:

```
def MyFunction(val1, val2):
    assert type(val1) == type(val2)
    ...
```

However, I would not like to raise an exception if, for example, the two types are of `<class 'numpy.float64>` and `<class 'float'>`. Is there any simple way to do this? I have thought about reducing the type strings by removing the module and memory parts, but I don't want to have many unnecessary operations inside this function.

Comment: Those aren't the same type. What do you *really* care about?

Comment: @user2357112 the function can take integers, floats, complex, np.array, and I want to assert that the input variables aren't a mixture of them.

Comment: Look at `np.can_cast`.

Comment: @hpaulj Perfect, thanks!

Comment: @obackhouse: Why not? Particularly mixed arrays and other types - mixed scalar/array handling is a common requirement in NumPy code. Also, checking the type won't do anything to stop you from mixing an array of int64 and an array of float64.

Comment: If you want to do this through type-switching, use the ABCs in the [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html) module, and use `isinstance` rather than `type() ==`. But you have to be careful, because a `float` or an `np.float32` will say it is an instance of `Complex` (because it _is_ usable as a complex number, just with j=0). So, you need to decide whether mixing float and complex means you have a valid complex operation or an error, and, if the latter, do things like `isinstance(n, Real) and not isinstance(n, Complex)`.

Comment: (Also, none of that will help if you want to treat, e.g., `Decimal` and `float` differently, because they're both implementations of the same abstract types on the numeric tower.)

Comment: You may want to look at [`numpy.asarray(x).dtype.kind`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html) (and be careful with `i`/`u`).